# re-initialize global configuration when rerunning TestCafe test in live mode

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

When using TestCafe in live mode (not using live runner) when it runs on detecting code change it doesn't reload my global variables.

In my test code I have a config page that I use to setup initial state for test and during test I modify this configuration so that I can track and check for expected changes.

For example I have something along lines of:

```
ConfigPage = {
  description: 'some description'
}
```

In my test code, along the way I want to do something like

```
ConfigPage.description = ConfigPage.description+' add to description'
```

This words, but not on live re-run. If live re-run is triggered, on start of test ConfigPage.description now has 'some description add to description' and not 'some description'

My ConfigPage file is a TypeScript class:

```
class ConfigurationPage {
  description: string
  constructor () {
    this.description = 'some description'
  }
}

export ConfigPage = new ConfigurationPage()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ConfigPage file is imported from the cache on the test re-run if it wasn't modified. So the ConfigurationPage object is instantiated only once and exported as a constant. If you change this file, the test will re-run with the result you expect.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, I was suspecting that there was some cache at play and hoping there was a way to prevent caching of certain files.